# How to disable nodes in JFace CheckboxTreeViewer?

Tags: eclipse, treeview, swt, jface, treeviewer

How can I disable a tree node in a `CheckboxTreeViewer`? Basically what I want is whenever a parent is selected in a check box tree all its children should be disabled and should not be possible to select. Also all the children should get unselected if any of them are previously selected before disabling them.
 Any ways??

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really supported by the viewer.

The best you can do is use the `addCheckStateListener` method to add an `ICheckStateListener` which reverses any unwanted check actions.